# String in one file whether present in another file or not

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I want to find the string present in one file if present in another file or not.

For example: file.txt contains->

**IamLookingforthispatternpleasehelpme**

pattern.txt->

**thispattern**

```
<?php
 if(strpos(file_get_contents("file.txt"),file_get_contents("pattern.txt"))!=FALSE){
        echo "found it!!";
}
else{
        echo "not able to find";
}
?>
```

I wrote above code and ran it but it outputs

> "not able to find"

How to do this i am new to php

**And to clarify txt files contain texts in above format only.**

Comment: What's the output of `echo file_get_contents("file.txt")`? What's the output of `echo file_get_contents("pattern.txt")`? Respect this warning: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php, i.e., use `!==false` instead of `!=false`, but if the pattern's not starting at position 0 in file.txt, as your example suggests, this should not be the main issue in your example.

Comment: output of echo file_get_contents("file.txt") is "IamLookingforthispatternpleasehelpme" and output of echo file_get_contents("pattern.txt") is also correct-> "thispattern".

Comment: I also used !==false with no success!

Comment: Ok, what happens if you insert the strings directly? `strpos("IamLookingforthispatternpleasehelpme","thispattern")!==false`

Comment: Yes for this it is outputting "found it!!"

Comment: Ok, what's the output for `echo bin2hex(file_get_contents("file.txt"));` and `echo bin2hex(file_get_contents("pattern.txt"));`? Should be `49616d4c6f6f6b696e67666f72746869737061747465726e706c6561736568656c706d65` and `746869737061747465726e`, thereby confirming that `746869737061747465726e` is contained in the first string? There are probably some invisible characters in the file which prevent a successful match... Which should show in the hex encoded string which won't contain invisible characters.

Comment: Yes i found the error! It was due to '\n' appended at the end when i echoed the file_get_contents(). It prevented the successful match! Thanks

Comment: When i echoed it showed like->

Comment: "IamLookingforthispatternpleasehelpme\n"

Comment: Hmmm, seems strange; and when you remove the newline character in the file it works? But I suppose that `strpos("IamLookingforthispatternpleasehelpme\nsomeNewLine\nSomeOther\n","thispattern")!==false` will yield "found it!!", nonetheless...? Edit: Ah, you had a `\n` in the pattern.txt file, you mean, I suppose?

Comment: i dont know whether '\n' was in the file but while echoing it showed me the new line after the string.

Comment: it is working now when i removed the newline!

Comment: Ok, tried to formulate an answer out of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `pattern.txt` file likely contains invisible characters which prevent a successful match.

Consider hex-dumping the string values with `bin2hex(file_get_contents("file.txt"))` and `bin2hex(file_get_contents("pattern.txt"))`, and compare whether the hex string of the pattern is actually contained within the hex string of the file, which will likely not be the case.